# How to write 2 sigma?

Tags: math-operators

I wanna to write 2 sigmas with lower and upper bound but I don't know how ?

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12pt]

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$$‎\sum^{N}_{n=0}{\sum_{m=1}^{(n+1)/2}\mu |c_n|\frac{n!}{(2m-1)!\pi ^{n-2m-2}‎
‎}|z|^{2m-1}‎}$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you getting at the moment? When I compile your sample code, I see two sums, each with their own lower and upper bound. What do you want differently?

Comment: See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to use `\limits_{lower}^{upper}` after `\sum`

```
\documentclass{amsart}[12pt]

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{environ} 
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum\limits^{N}_{n=0}{\sum\limits_{m=1}^{(n+1)/2}\mu |c_n|\frac{n!}{(2m-1)!\pi ^{n-2m-2}‎ ‎}|z|^{2m-1}‎}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this output differ from OP's output?  Within display mode, isn't `\sum` already with `\limits` by default?

Comment: @Teepeemm I think before the question was edited by Werner, the formula was enclosed in one sign `$`, but now I think, it does not matter.